# Is there a single word for "turn a blind eye"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've heard the phrase "turn a blind eye" and I'm wondering if there is a single word to represent this. In my context, I'm looking to describe something negative, for instance:

> She turned a blind eye to her child's behaviour when she discovered he was bullying other kids at school.
>
> A bad supervisor will turn a blind eye to his or her employees' poor work habits.

*Neglect* doesn't seem appropriate in some of these contexts. I've thought about using *disregard* or *ignore* but I'm not sure if they convey the same meaning/what the differences are.

Is there a single verb to represent this phrase?

Comment: _ignore_ seems closest to me. I don't think there's a single word that conveys the nuance of the phrase, though.

Comment: why must it be a single word?  To *feign ignorance* could be used but it is two words.

Comment: As I got -1, can someone explain how I can improve the question? I'm usually on Stack Overflow so I'm not that familiar with this community.

Comment: It is probably because you didn't provide evidence of having looked at the dictionary definitions. I didn't down vote you, but this is a stated reason for down voting. Please take a few minutes to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: If you insist on a single word, I see nothing wrong with "ignore".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Tolerate* and *condone* go to the other end of the spectrum:
they imply that the person knows of the offense but does nothing about it.

Answer (score 12):

[Ignore](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=ignore): to refuse to pay attention to; disregard.

From the Latin *ignōrāre*: *in*- ‘not’ + *gno*-, a base meaning ‘know’. It implies the refusal to take notice of or acknowledge; disregard intentionally.

[Disregard](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disregard):

> to pay no attention or heed to; ignore; to show no evidence of attention concerning (something); to treat without proper respect or attentiveness. - AHDEL

Answer (score 8):

To [*overlook*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/overlook), to *ignore*, to *disregard*, to *neglect* should be appropriate to use in place of this idiom. The meaning of the idiom is *to ignore deliberately, to pretend not to notice.* (See the idiom's entries in [WordReference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=turn%20a%20blind%20eye) and [CollinsDictionary.com](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/turn-a-blind-eye-to).) In fact there are many synonyms for this.

According to [Phrases.org](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/turn-a-blind-eye.html), the origin of the idiom goes like this: Admiral Horatio Nelson is supposed to have said this when wilfully disobeying a signal to withdraw during a naval engagement during the battle of Copenhagen in 1801, when the Admiral Sir Hyde Parker sent a signal (by use of flags) for Nelson to disengage. Nelson was convinced he could win if he persisted and that's when he said to have 'turned a blind eye' on the flag signals. Chapter VII of the biography [*The Life of Horatio Lord Nelson* by Robert Southey](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/947/947-h/947-h.htm#link2HCH0007) claims the actual words of Nelson to Captain Thomas Foley were:

> "... You know, Foley," turning to the captain, "I have only one eye,—I have a 
>   right to be blind sometimes:" and then putting the glass to his blind eye, in 
>   that mood of mind which sports with bitterness, he exclaimed, "I really do not see the signal!"

And thus the idiom "to turn a blind eye" on something/someone.

Thus, using *ignore*, *dismiss*, *disregard*, *overlook*, *pretend not to see* should be fine depending on the exact requirement of the sentence. For example:

1. Only parents could **overlook** that kind of behavior.

   Only parents could *turn a blind eye* on such behavior.
2. Teachers **overlooked** the bad handwriting in cases where students were 
   able to secure only passing marks.

   Teachers *turned a blind eye* to the handwriting in cases where students 
   were able to secure only passing marks.
3. The corrupt inspector agreed to **pretend not to see** the safety 
   violations.

   The corrupt inspector agreed to *turn a blind eye* to the safety violations.
4. The Management **ignores** the bullying at the workplace.

   The Management *turns a blind eye* on the bullying at the workplace.

Comment: From a historical point of view, Parker´s order to withdraw was designed to be disregarded if Nelson wished to continue the battle.  The British Articles of War were strict, and so Nelson could only withdraw if ordered to do so, no matter what the situation, as seen by the execution of Admiral Byng half a century earlier. Parker´s words when giving the order were *"I will make the signal of recall for Nelson's sake. If he is in condition to continue the action, he will disregard it; if he is not, it will be an excuse for his retreat and no blame can be imputed to him."*

Answer (score 4):

The normal word for this *overlook*.

Comment: "Overlook" often denotes failure to notice as opposed to willful disregard...

Comment: ... Yes, but "overlook" often denotes willful disregard as opposed to failure to notice.

Comment: @RustyTuba it's impossible to overlook something you haven't noticed. I think this is probably a good an answer as one is going to get; if there were a perfect synonym with exactly the same nuance, we wouldn't have the expression "turn a blind eye" at all.

Comment: @Jon: That's odd, because most definitions of overlook say precisely "fail to see or notice." Yes, it can also be used with a willful meaning, but not always. That's why I feel "disregard" (always willful) may be better.

Comment: -1 I can't overlook the fact that you have failed to provide any references to back up your claim. (Hatarchy?)

Answer (score 3):

Obviously there are lots of great answers above, but I thought I'd add a fun one that I always liked even though it is archaic. It is the word "wink". If, for example, you "wink" at someone's transgression you are closing your eyes to it. It is an archaic word but I always liked the mind picture it evoked, sufficient that even those unfamiliar with the word's particular meaning, it would nonetheless convey the sense.

"Since the writing was so dynamic the reviewer often winked at his sloppy grammar so that he could enjoy the story."

[Wiktionary: Wink](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wink)
 - (archaic, intransitive) To turn a blind eye.

Answer (score 2):

Neglected will be suitable word in this context. According to Cambridge Dictionary Neglect is defined as "to not give enough care or attention to people or things that are your responsibility".

Answer (score 1):

***close one's eyes to (something)***

> To ignore something, to pretend that something is not really happening
>
> *The man closed his eyes to the problems that were happening in his company*. [The Idiom Connection](http://www.idiomconnection.com/eyes.html)

Answer (score 0):

in the most egregious cases, **complicit** or "be **complicit**"

> involved with others in an illegal activity or wrongdoing (Oxford)

When a wrong-doing or injustice is committed and others see this but do nothing, they are essentially complicit via inaction, even if they didn't explicitly help the offender execute the crime.

Answer (score -1):

## [disengage](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disengage)

> to stop being involved with a person or group : to stop taking part in something

Used as an intransitive verb, it is more specifically defined as:

> to release or detach oneself

Answer (score -1):

**Connive at/in** carries the same meaning as turn a blind eye or deaf ear. It means to secretly allow (something considered immoral, illegal, wrong, or harmful) to occur: *you have it in your power to connive at my escape.*
From Latin *connivere* ‘shut the eyes (to),’ from *con-* ‘together’ + an unrecorded word related to *nictare* ‘to wink.’